How to make 3d character into flat style
I'm doing art style. Would anyone know how to make 3D models flat to look like ancient Egyptian drawings? and maybe parent with Rigify. so the character can move and rotate while being flat.



By rotate do you mean rotate on an axis or rotate the joints?

Do you mean something like a toon shader?
